# NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.post_id django

Tags: python, django

I have the basics of a blogs app (I have been following Corey Schafer's tutorial, part 10, if that matters) and I am trying to post and display comments on the post that other users have wrote that only relate to that post. Similar to that of a comment section on Facebook or YouTube.

Currently I'm displaying all comments in the database on every post because I don't know how to filter the results to only show comments for the specific post and I also don't know how to post comments to a specific post, that's where I get the error.

My code is below:

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment'] = Comment.objects.all()
        return context

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py (This is the urls.py file in my main app where I'm calling the blogs app views)

```
path('posts/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
path('posts/<int:pk>/comment', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment-create'),
```

I then have this form in a file called *comment_form.html* that I can connect to when I got to http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/5/comment but when I click reply I get 
**IntegrityError at /posts/5/comment NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.post_id**

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Reply to Post </legend>
    {{ form|crispy}}
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">. 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Reply</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If someone could throw their eye over it and let me know if you can find anything that I could do to get it to work, I would greatly appreciate it. Let me know if you need more information/code.

Thanks

Comment: What fields are being sent to the comment model via the form? It seems like you passed the user to the form but I don't see where you pass the foreign key "post" for your comment model.

The NOT NULL constraint means that you are trying to insert a row to a table while leaving a field NULL that has the NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: So I am only using the content field as an input box in the form and then setting the user in the form_valid function. I think I need the “post” value to be the same as the primary that it is in the Post database, as that is how it is set in the PostCreateView(which I haven’t shown as that works okay), but I am unsure how to do that for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you're creation form is missing a non nullable field, that's why django is complaining about the "NOT NULL CONSTRAINT"
so you have to add the post field to the form fields, or you can add it in the form_valid method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

if you want to ignore the post field, you can put null=True in the Comment Model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this worked perfectly! Do you know if I can filter the PostDetailView extra content anyway better than using Comment.objects.all() to only display what information is necessary instead of all of the results in the database, no hassle if you don’t know.

Comment: you're welcome :) , yes, actually you can get the related comments to the post by doing this : ```context['comment'] = self.object.comment_set```

Comment: Thanks, the help is greatly appreciated :)